# How to use Jest and Supertest with Fastify?

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, supertest, fastify

I'm trying to use Jest and Supertest with Fastify. I have this test file.

```js
// @ts-nocheck
import { FastifyInstance } from 'fastify'
import request from 'supertest'
import app from '../app'

let server: FastifyInstance

beforeAll(async () => {
    server = app.server;
})

afterAll(() => {
    server.close()
})

test('Should get a 200 OK', async () => {
    const response = await request(server).get('/')
    expect(response.status).toBe(200)
})
```

My `app.ts`:

```js
import fastify from 'fastify'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

dotenv.config()

import appRoute from './routes/app'

const app = fastify({ logger: true })

app.register(appRoute)

export default app
```

But I always get a timeout... Could anyone provide an example of how to use Jest and Supertest with Fastify?

Comment: Why you don't use app.inject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example in the official document at the bottom about writing testings with `supertest`. See [testing](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Guides/Testing/)

Make sure you call the `done` callback of the `fasity.register()` API.

`index.js`:

```js
const Fastify = require('fastify');

const app = Fastify({ logger: true });

app.register((instance, opts, done) => {
  instance.get('/', (request, reply) => {
    reply.send({ hello: 'world' });
  });
  done();
});

module.exports = app;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const supertest = require('supertest');
const app = require('./');

afterAll(() => app.close());

test('GET `/` route', async () => {
  await app.ready();

  const response = await supertest(app.server)
    .get('/')
    .expect(200)
    .expect('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

  expect(response.body).toEqual({ hello: 'world' });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
❯ npm run test
$ jest
{"level":30,"time":1673234788774,"pid":70,"hostname":"noderfv2fs-ky0o","reqId":"req-1","req":{"method":"GET","url":"/","hostname":"127.0.0.1:62766"},"msg":"incoming request"}
{"level":30,"time":1673234788777,"pid":70,"hostname":"noderfv2fs-ky0o","reqId":"req-1","res":{"statusCode":200},"responseTime":2.5850000000000364,"msg":"request completed"}
 PASS  ./index.test.js
  ✓ GET `/` route (489 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.269 s, estimated 3 s
Ran all test suites.
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-rfv2fs?file=index.test.js)(Open using Chrome, there is a bug when run `npm run test` using Microsoft Edge)

Answer (score 2):

before I answer your question, I would recommend using the built-in feature `fastify.inject()` which uses [light-my-request](https://github.com/fastify/light-my-request) for some reasons

- it doesn't create a test server, whereas superTest silently creates a test server
- it waits until all plugins are registered and the server is ready for test
- no need to install an additional package "superTest"

I will explain how to perform the test in either case

### using .inject():

```
let app = Fastify({...});
app.inject({method: 'GET', URL: '/'})
  .then(res=>{/
   //Make the actual test here, using Jest or any library of your choice
   expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200)
   // ...other expectations
  })
```

or you can build your fake request like this:

```
app.inject()
 .get('/')
 .headers({...})
 .then(res=>{ /* your test here */}
```

### using SuperTest

this method is a bit similar to the previous one, with some additional work

```
let app = Fastify({...})

//We need to wait until the app is ready for the test
await app.ready();

//Now we can use superTest to start our test server
superTest(app.server)
 .get('/')
 .expect(200)
 // ...other expectations
```

Comment: This answer should be the Accpted answer